# Capture UTC Time From String And Format All DateTime To It

Tags: c#, datetime, fedex

I have a date that is being returned in a string format

```
string utcdt = "2017-01-01T15:48:00-07:00";
```

How could I extract the `07:00` Mountain Time from the string above and format any date to this regional formatting?

I do not want to change timezones on my computer, as the UTC time returned to the variable `utcdt` can vary depending, and all other dates used in my WinForm app would need to conform to the same timezone specifications.

**Edit**
I am using the FEDEx API and this is one format of the date returnerd

```
string utcdt = "2017-01-01T15:48:00-07:00";
```

Now later in the application there is

```
foreach (TrackingDateOrTimestamp timestamp in trackDetail.DatesOrTimes)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", timestamp.Type, timestamp.DateOrTimestamp);
```

Which returns the data in my local time - meaning

```
01/01/2017 17:48:00
```

I am trying to come up with a solution to have the dates be consistent.

Comment: You don't have a time zone there - you have an offset. Presumably in summer you'd want to format it with an offset of -6 rather than -7. Really, you should be trying to work out what time zone the user wants to see it in rather than just knowing a single offset.

Comment: @JonSkeet - you lost me...I have an offset?

Comment: Yes, that's what the "-07:00" is. It's a UTC offset, saying that local time is 7 hours behind UTC. You don't have "Mountain Time" anywhere in your string.

Comment: DateTime utcTime = DateTime.Parse(utcdt);  The output will be in your local timezone so EST will show 2 hours later 17:48.

Comment: @jdweng - I am using the FedEx API and when the data is returned utcdt is returned as above, however another variable is returned that is in EST.  I want to format the second variable to the same time zone (constraint) as utcdt

Comment: @JonSkeet - That does not make much sense to me as, if you look up UTC 07:00 it shows Mountain Time Zone  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9207:00

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard: But in the summer, Pacific Time is at UTC-7. **A UTC offset is not a time zone.**

Comment: In fact, that's clear in the page *you* linked to: "In North America, it is observed in the Mountain Time Zone during standard time, and in the Pacific Time Zone during the other 8 months (see Daylight saving time). A few places use it year-round." So just from the offset, you can't tell whether the user is in one of the places that uses it all-year-round or not.

Comment: You first want to get all times in local time.  Then format time in timezone you need as a string.

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard - you might want to read the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and the [dst tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) which explain these things well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTimeOffset` class to parse the string into the local time and it's offset from UTC. You can then save the offset as a `TimeSpan`.

Later on then again use the `DateTimeOffset` class to convert another `DateTime` you have to use the same offset:

```
string dto = "2017-01-01T15:48:00-07:00";

DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dto);

DateTime utcDateTime = dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime;
TimeSpan timezoneOffset = dateTimeOffset.Offset;


MessageBox.Show("UTC DateTime: " + utcDateTime);
MessageBox.Show("Offset: " + timezoneOffset);

DateTimeOffset nowWithOffset = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(timezoneOffset);

MessageBox.Show("Now in other timezone: " + nowWithOffset.ToString("O"));
```

---

Note what other commentators have written: This does not correctly deal with Daylight Saving Time. In order to deal with that, you actually need to know the real timezone.

Comment: Why convert to DateTime at all ?? This will bring back the problems that were solved by using DateTimeOffset

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just for illustration purposes in this answer

Comment: @NineBerry - I made some minor edits to prevent confusion.